# Query by key inside array column

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table **shift** and I want to get the shifts that have a dict with id = 2 in the value of reading_format in the shift_hours column.

```
INSERT INTO shift (id, name, shift_hours)
values (10, 'shift 1', '{"timezone": "UTC+1", "reading_format": [
                    {"id": 0, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 1, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 2, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 3, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 4, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 5, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "23:00"}]},
                    {"id": 6, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "23:00"}]}
                ]}');
```

I'm doing it like this with sqlalchemy:

```
shifts = db.session.query(Shift).all()

for shift in shifts:
    for slot in shift.shift_hours['parsing_format']:
        # do stuff
```

Is there a way to filter with sqlalchemy directly?

Something like:

```
shifts = db.session.query(Shift).filter(Shift.shift_hours.reading_format.id == 2).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have reached to your question

```
mylist=[
                    {"id": 0, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 1, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 2, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 3, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 4, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "20:00"}]},
                    {"id": 5, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "23:00"}]},
                    {"id": 6, "periods": [{"start": "08:00", "end": "12:00"}, {"start": "14:00", "end": "23:00"}]}
                ]

 

#for slot in shift.shift_hours['parsing_format']:
#the above statement is same as below...
for eachslot in mylist:
    if eachslot['id']==2:
        print('ID=',eachslot['id'],"===>",eachslot['periods'])
        print('1st shift:',eachslot['periods'][0])
        print('1st shift:','START:',eachslot['periods'][0]['start'])
        print('1st shift:','START:',eachslot['periods'][0]['end'])
        print("---------------------------------------")
        print('2nd shift:',eachslot['periods'][1])
        print('2nd shift:','START:',eachslot['periods'][1]['start'])
        print('2nd shift:','START:',eachslot['periods'][1]['end'])
```

The OUTPUT WILL BE:

```
ID= 2 ===> [{'start': '08:00', 'end': '12:00'}, {'start': '14:00', 'end': '20:00'}]
1st shift: {'start': '08:00', 'end': '12:00'}
1st shift: START: 08:00
1st shift: START: 12:00
---------------------------------------
2nd shift: {'start': '14:00', 'end': '20:00'}
2nd shift: START: 14:00
2nd shift: START: 20:00
```